# How can I upgrade ffmpeg in CentOS 6.x

Tags: command-line, centos, upgrade, ffmpeg, packages

At first, I've downloaded ffmpeg 0.6.5. and it works. But when I'm trying to use '-vf' option, Terminal said there's no such command.

So I asked this on Super User and someone said that the cause is my ffmpeg version being too old.

So here's what I want to do: upgrade my ffmpeg 0.6.5 to 1.2. Below is what I've tried.

1. Download and install yasm and ffmpeg-1.2
2. Execute `./configure` in my folder where ffmpeg has downloaded.
3. Execute `make` command.
4. Execute `make install` command.

There's no error while I proceed, but when I enter the command `ffmpeg -version` it still
shows 0.6.5. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a path problem. Originally `ffmpeg` is installed in the directory where the `gz` file(or `bz2`) is.

So if you do `./configure` → `make` → `make install`, it works, but only in that directory (for this case it was `/home/username/Downloads/ffmpeg-1.2`).

If you want to use the `ffmpeg` command anywhere, you give some options to the `./configure` command, like `.configure --prefix=/usr`.

So, that's the way I worked it out.